# Tweak tumblr share bookmarklet

Tags: bookmarklet, tumblr

I use Tumblr's sharing bookmarklet a lot (http://www.tumblr.com/goodies). This opens up a popup window with basically the following url:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/share?v=3&u=<current page url>&t=<current page title>
```

However I almost always change a few things (use the queue instead of posting right away and set a specific tag).

Does anyone know if the share URL accepts extra parameters? That way I could make one bookmark that tags the post with "x" and queues it, and another that invokes the usual behavior. I can't find a useful documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet would be to ask your question in the Google Groups group for the Tumblr API.  I do know that the parameters, or *state* in the parlance of Tumblr, can be affected so long as those attributes are specified in your script coding. Also, you have to be pretty specific about what *type* of post you’re making, like text, photo / photoset, audio, link, video, quote, and so forth.